# calling a function with delay

Tags: python, multithreading, job-scheduling

I got this practice interview question.

Implement a job scheduler which takes in a function f and an integer n, and calls f after n milliseconds.

I have a very simple solution:

```
import time

def schedulerX(f,n):
    time.sleep(0.001*n)
    f
```

However, the suggested solution is much more elaborated as below.
I dont understand whats the purpose behind all this extra code.
Please enlightened me.

```
from time import sleep
import threading

class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fns = [] # tuple of (fn, time)
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.poll)
        t.start()

    def poll(self):
        while True:
            now = time() * 1000
            for fn, due in self.fns:
                if now > due:
                    fn()
            self.fns = [(fn, due) for (fn, due) in self.fns if due > now]
            sleep(0.01)

    def delay(self, f, n):
        self.fns.append((f, time() * 1000 + n))
```

Comment: btw: your implementation is buggy. you do not call `f`. it should read `f()`

Comment: Their implementation doesn't match their requirements. They asked for something that takes in "a" function. Their implementation runs a list of functions, and keeps spinning, waiting for more functions to be added. And any long-running function is going to make any other functions that are added after it to run later than expected. Also, they messed up their import statements, so this won't even run.

Comment: @mypetlion Thanks for the insights. I subscribed to this thingy called daily coding problem and pay $9/month for the daily solution. hahaha one thing I dont like about this service is they dont have a lot of test cases for novice like me...

Comment: @Marcin Onlowski I dont understand what do you mean read f(). can you give an code example ?

Comment: @mypetlion Would you give some code examples to validate your points

Comment: Try this: `s = Scheduler(); s.delay(lambda: sleep(99999), 1); s.delay(lambda: print('this function runs way later than probably desired'), 3)` The second function passed in is expected to run after 3 milliseconds. But it won't run until much later than that because the first function blocks until it completes.

Comment: This reference implementation is also buggy in the sense there is a race condition. While `fn()` is running, other functions within the array could elapse past their deadline. The list should be partitioned ahead of time, so that no functions are missed.

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, your solution is 'blocking': it prevents anything else from happening while it's waiting to run. The intent of the suggested solution is to let you schedule the job and then carry on with other stuff in the meantime.

As for an explanation of what the suggested code is doing:

You'd first create a `Scheduler`, which would start its own thread that effectively runs in the background, and which will run the jobs.

```
scheduler = Scheduler()
```

In your code, you could then schedule whatever jobs you want without having to wait for them to run:

```
def my_recurring_job():
    # Do some stuff in the background, then re-run this job again
    # in one second.

    ### Do some stuff ###

    scheduler.delay(my_recurring_job, 1000)

scheduler.delay(lambda: print("5 seconds passed!"), 5 * 1000)
scheduler.delay(lambda: print("2 hours passed!"), 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
scheduler.delay(my_recurring_job, 1000)

# You can keep doing other stuff without waiting
```

The scheduler's thread is just looping forever in its `poll` method, running any jobs whose time has come, and then sleeping 0.01 seconds and checking again. There's a small bug in the code where if now == due, the job won't run, but it also won't be kept for later. It should be `if now >= due:` instead.

A more advanced scheduler might use a `threading.Condition` instead of polling 100 times a second:

```
import threading
from time import time

class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fns = [] # tuple of (fn, time)

        # The lock prevents 2 threads from messing with fns at the same time;
        # also lets us use Condition
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

        # The condition lets one thread wait, optionally with a timeout,
        # and lets other threads wake it up
        self.condition = threading.Condition(self.lock)

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.poll)
        t.start()

    def poll(self):
        while True:
            now = time() * 1000

            with self.lock:
                # Prevent the other thread from adding to fns while we're sorting
                # out the jobs to run now, and the jobs to keep for later

                to_run = [fn for fn, due in self.fns if due <= now]
                self.fns = [(fn, due) for (fn, due) in self.fns if due > now]

            # Run all the ready jobs outside the lock, so we don't keep it
            # locked longer than we have to
            for fn in to_run:
                fn()

            with self.lock:
                if not self.fns:
                    # If there are no more jobs, wait forever until a new job is 
                    # added in delay(), and notify_all() wakes us up again
                    self.condition.wait()
                else:
                    # Wait only until the soonest next job's due time.
                    ms_remaining = min(due for fn, due in self.fns) - time()*1000
                    if ms_remaining > 0:
                        self.condition.wait(ms_remaining / 1000)

    def delay(self, f, n):
        with self.lock:
            self.fns.append((f, time() * 1000 + n))

            # If the scheduler thread is currently waiting on the condition,
            # notify_all() will wake it up, so that it can consider the new job's
            # due time.
            self.condition.notify_all()
```

Comment: is there an small indentation error above on the line with "scheduler.delay(my_recurring_job, 1000)", or am I misunderstanding? =) Thanks <3

Comment: It should be right. The top one (the indented one) happens within the my_recurring_job() function: every time the function runs, it then re-schedules itself to run again in 1 second. The bottom one (not indented) is the one-time action that schedules the function initially.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences (in theory).

The first, and most important, I think, is that your solution can, effectively, only schedule one function at a time. So, for example, say you wanted to run a function `f1` 10 milliseconds from now, and another function `f2` 10 milliseconds after that.

You would not be able to do that easily, since something like `schedulerX(f1, 10); schedulerX(f2, 10)` would *wait for `f1` to finish running before starting the wait for `f2`*. If `f1` takes an hour, your scheduling of `f2` will be totally wrong.

The intent of the second version is to, apparently, have the timer and each function running in a separate thread, so that one function call does not block another.

However, as others have noted in the comments, the imports are wrong, it takes a `list` of functions even though the problem specification says *a* function, and it doesn't actually work the way I described it, so more or less, there's no difference.